# How to select fields from other tables if they're not null in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently requested to make a query that will be get name of fields from other tables if they're not null!
Let's say w've tables like that:

Student

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mehdi | 22 |
| 1 | Amina | 26 |

Math

| id | section |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Algebra |
| 2 | Analysis |
| 3 | Geometry |

English

| id | section |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Grammar |
| 2 | Speaking |
| 3 | Vocabulary |

Exam

| idStudent | idMath | idEnglish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Null |
| 1 | Null | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | Null |

We want to query make this expected result:

Exam

| idStudent | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Algebra |
| 1 | Speaking |
| 2 | Algebra |

I've tried so far:

```sql
select idStudent,m.section Subject 
from Exam exam, Student s, Math m, English eng
where s.id = exam.idStudent 
and m.id=exam.idMath 
and exam.idEnglish is null
union
select idStudent,eng.section Subject 
from Exam exam, Student s, Math m, English eng
where s.id = exam.idStudent 
and eng.id=exam.idEnglish 
and exam.idMath is null
```

Is there a better way to do that!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1992) Years`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Thanks for your edit! but it doesn't matter the way of joining tables more than solving the query problem!

Comment: I would start by putting all the data from the English and Math table into a single COURSE table. Then most of the problem will disappear

Comment: _it doesn't matter the way of joining tables_ Oh but it most definitely does matter

Comment: and then change the `Exam` table to be `id_student, id_course`

Comment: Maybe you're right, maybe I'm not the one who create the db! but request to make this query, the scheme of db is not helpful at all, but just asked is there a better way doing that with one query rather than two?

Comment: No, given this schema there isn't a cleaner way to do this than a union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database model is far from ideal since it uses one table per course; that means that every time a course is added, then a new table would need to be created. A typical model would include a single table for all courses.

Anyway, in your case you can do:

```
select e.idstudent, c.section from exam e join math c on c.id = e.idmath
union all
select e.idstudent, c.section from exam e join english c on c.id = e.idenglish
```

Also, please use modern join syntax instead of the 1980s join syntax, since it's much easier to read and the debug.